# Informix - Getting all descendants of a parent

Tags: recursive, informix

I have a table with two columns, `Parent` and `Child`. Need to get the list of all descendants associated with the parent records.

Source Table:

```
+----+-----------+
| Parent | Child |
+----+-----------+
|  a     |     b |
|  b     |     c |
|  c     |     d |
|  d     |     e |
|  e     |     f |
|  f     |     x |
+----+-----------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+----+-----------+
| Parent | Child |
+----+-----------+
|  a     |     b |  // As b is the child of a, all the descendants of b 
|  a     |     c |  // are also descendants of a. 
|  a     |     d |
|  a     |     e |
|  a     |     f |
|  a     |     x |
|  b     |     c |  // As c is the child of b, all the descendants of c 
|  b     |     d |  // are also descendants of b.
|  b     |     e |
|  b     |     f |
|  b     |     x |
|  c     |     d |
|  c     |     e |
|  c     |     f |
|  c     |     x |
|  d     |     e |
|  d     |     f |
|  d     |     x |
|  e     |     f |
|  e     |     x |
|  f     |     x |
+----+-----------+
```

Informix 11.50 doesn't have recursive CTEs (common table expressions). `CONNECT BY` can help about recursion levels, paths etc., but I can not get expected result using `CONNECT BY`. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Using the `CONNECT BY` syntax (similar to Oracle's) which allows recursive queries:

```
select connect_by_root parent as ancestor, 
       child
from x                            -- table name
connect by prior child = parent
order siblings by parent ;
```

Tested in [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/NMOJ68252)

Answer (score 0):

Great! My Informix version (12.10.FC7W1) did not accept "order siblings by parent" (error "317: The statement failed because you must have the same number of selected columns  in each UNION, INTERSECT, or MINUS query."), so I changed it into "order by 1, 2" to get the expected result.